# How can I find out why the internet connection speed in our LAN is so slow?

Tags: virus, lan, internet-connection, connection

The internet connection speed in our LAN has been slow down for several days.

- Is it possible that a virus is the cause of that?
- How can I detect the cause of this low speed?

---

**EDIT :**

I closed all apps and I run from command prompt : `netstat -b -v` and the output is :

```
Connexions actives

  Proto  Adresse locale         Adresse distante          Etat
  TCP    Ambre-28:1118          toolbar.iad.ask.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT      188
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WININET.dll
  [Updater.exe]


C:\Documents and Settings\Ambre-28>
```

So there is an unexpected connection opened by the `toolbar.iad.ask.com`. How to kill this connection ?

Comment: what have you did to LAN recently ?

Comment: What does the network administrator say happen "on the wire"?

Comment: He didn't know what's happening !

Comment: Somebody installed the ASK.com Toolbar so uninstall it. Can you just wipe the computer in question?  Of course Ask.com is not malware its just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If a virus is opening network connections it may reduce the available speed for you.

You can do a basic check by running "netstat"  and see if any unexpected connections are open.

Comment: What are the options to use in that case ?

Comment: i assume you are using windows. close your browsers,chat clients, game etc (all apps that you know use network) . Then run netstat on command prompt . Ideally there should be no connections opened from your PC.

Comment: I displayed the output of the netstat command in my question, see my edit.